# generating random number pairs for forming 2 dimensional random point

Tags: c++, c, translation

I'm trying to understand one stupid sentence:

"This function will perform a single experiment. It will generate npoints random rational number pairs (x, y), to
form npoints random 2 dimensional points. The x, and y coordinates of these points should remain in the interval
[-r, r]"

So, in this function, npoints is integer, with value 1000, and can be different value. Functions gets numbers a and b and degree thera1 and theta2, And also r, which is `r(θ) = ae^bθ`. So, can anyone explain me, what actually this function must do?

PS. Its not actually bug, the problem is that i can't understand it may be because my English is not so good, sorry for that, but its not for website of English language as its about codes :)

Comment: No, it's totally unclear...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth , thanks for support, its question from teacher, thats why i'm thinking that problem is in me)))

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about understanding a badly-worded question, not about programming.


Answer (score 1, accepted):

My interpretation is as follows:

> "This function will perform a single experiment. It will generate
>   npoints random rational number pairs (x, y),

You need to generate random x/y coordinate pairs. "Rational" just means that the numbers can be written as the quotient of two integers (so e and PI are out).

> to form npoints random 2 dimensional points.

You should end up with "npoints" in total.

> The x, and y coordinates of these points should remain in the interval [-r, r]"

So, you need to keep the points all within "r" distance of 0. In other words, no point will have an x or y coordinate smaller than -r or larger than r. In a function form this would look something like:

```
/* The point structure */
struct POINT {
   int x;
   int y;
};

/* npoints    -- The number of points to generate */
/* range      -- The maximum (positive/negative) value for the points */
POINT *GetRandomCoordinates(int npoints, int range);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: ok, it explains most things, but where in this function thetas can be used?

Comment: @Emin I only tried to interpret the single sentence which is what you had in quotes. I don't see anything in that sentence about theta. Either there is something more to the question or it has to do with the distribution of the points. I can't guess though from the information I have!

Comment: That sentence was copy-paste from question paper. Also, I know that it must return value for list[i] which is double array.

Comment: How do you know what it returns or takes? If you know these things then there must be more to the question!

Comment: Because i must get list from 0 to n from this function and print them.

Comment: BTW, what is GetRandomCoordinates? It is function that will create random number from npoints to range or something else?

Comment: I wrote a function prototype for you - this would be what I thought your professor might be asking for. I assumed this was a code writing question not an explanation question. I hoped it might help you in your understanding - even if you don't understand english too well, understanding code is very easy : )

Comment: a small correction, repeating numbers can still be rational. The only requirement of a rational number is that it can be represented as the quotient of two integers.

Comment: @RedAlert Noted & Fixed!